# Chrome master password

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, google-chrome-extensions

I have read that Chrome developers will never add a master password to chrome without any real reason: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/k6JmRoGJp5w/Th9hdBwqIU0J

Is there any solution to set master password to Google Chrome to protect my stored passwords?

Also I'm using KeePass 1, so extension for KeePass 2 is not suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no reliable way at the moment.

There are reports that Chrome team is working on [less-privileged accounts](http://browserfame.com/997/chrome-managed-user-account), which also means that there would be some kind of security for master (primary) account, like authenticating users before accessing critical data.

Well, you should try some extensions like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/browser-lock/ofilhkhdoiamdkbgciniekmdgjehaadm/details?hl=en-US) and [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/browser-locker/hnnecpmejibghfcebehiepoppfhceppl?hl=en-US), but these are not the true solution.

Comment: The problem is any malware can get your passwords. That's why we need master passwords.

Comment: I don't think so. I *believe* that passwords are not saved as plain text.

Comment: That's true. Any malware can get them because it can access to full Chrome data. PoC: http://securityxploded.com/chromepassworddecryptor.php

Comment: @arpitnext: They are saved encrypted, yes...but the encryption key is also saved there, so the encryption is kinda useless if someone has file-level access to the PC.